# Why the expression *(b++) doesn't evaluate the b++ first?

Tags: c++, pointers, operators, operator-precedence

I'm trying to understand how the parentheses affects the precedence in an expression:

```
int arr[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; 
auto b = arr;
std::cout << *(++b) << std::endl;

// output : 1
```

In this code I get the expected output but if I change it to:

```
std::cout << *(b++) << std::endl;
// output 0
```

I get `0` as output. Because of the parentheses I though `b++` will be evaluated first and then de-referencing will occur. It seems I was wrong, then I removed the parentheses completely and test with `*++b` and `*b++` and get the same results.Does that mean the parentheses don't affect the precedence on this kind of expressions ? And why are the results of this two expressions are  equivelant:

```
*(b + 1) 
*(++b)
```

But it's not the case with `*(b++)` ?

Comment: Because that's pretty much the *definition* of postfix increment? Please explain what you think it should do and how that differs from prefix increment (`++b`).

Comment: tl;dr `b++ == b`, the parentheses do not magically change the result of the evaluation.

Comment: @delnan yeah I'm aware of the difference but that is the parentheses I'm concerning about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *does* evaluate the `b++` first. `b++` increments `b` and returns the *previous* value of `b`, *before* the increment happened. The result of `b++` and the value of `b` afterwards are different. Think of it as (using `int` instead of `int *` because a reference-to-pointer makes the signature ugly):

```
int postfix_increment(int &x) {
    int result = x;
    x = x + 1;
    return result;
}
```

(Except that using the incremented value [before the next sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/395760) is undefined behavior.)

If you introduce a temporary variable for the result of the parenthesis, to make sure it's evaluated first, it may be easier to see the difference:

```
int *tmp = b++;
// At this point, b == tmp + 1!
std::cout << *tmp << std::endl;
```

Comment: okey it makes it clear. btw I guess you are missing a `*` in tmp

Comment: @Selman22 Yeah, missed that `b` is a pointer, not an int. Luckily is makes absolutely no difference for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`*(b++)` is equivalent to storing the old pointer, incrementing the pointer and dereferencing the old pointer

```
int* post_increment(int* b) 
{
   int* old = b;
   ++b;
   return old;
}
```

It is an instructive exercise to write a thin iterator wrapper around a plain pointer. When writing user-defined iterators, the above `post_increment()` function is usually written an overloaded `operator++(int)`. The `int` argument is purely to distinguish it from the pre-increment operator `operator++()`. In addition, you'd need an overloaded `operator*()` to dereference an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

`*(b+1)` works because you do math. Math takes parentheses into account. Only after Math is done, the expression gets evaluated.

`*(++b)` works because you increment before evaluation (prefix increment).

`*(b++)` doesn't work because you increment after evaluation (postfix increment).